# Image as the game world background, scale sprites (items)

Tags: javascript, canvas, background, scale

I making (my second) game in javascript/canvas (escape the room). Background image = game world (width/height). So if I change a game size from 2300x1080 to 2500x1080, items/object like door does not extend. Door image does not cover the hole (exit).

mycode html:

```
<canvas id="drawSurface" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
```

javacript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("drawSurface").getContext('2d');
// images
var bg = new Image;
    bg.src = "http://s10.ifotos.pl/img/bgpng_aerpsqq.png";
var door = new Image;
    door.src = "http://img.bizator.com/a/2002865733/w500/3-front-door-and-plastic-windows.jpg";

// game world
var game = {
    width: 2300,
    height:1080,
}

example();

function example(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(example);

    canvas.clearRect(0,0,window.screen.width,window.screen.height);

    canvas.drawImage(bg,-200,0,game.width, game.height);
    canvas.drawImage(door,1330,503,door.width,door.height);     
};
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/01sLdpb8/6/

How to properly scale background + sprites (items). I tried this (but not working good):

1) door.width + (game.width / canvas.width)

2) door.width * (game.width/drawSurface.width)

Should i use canvas.transform() (matrix) ? How i can calculate new x,y,width,height for items/objects if I change the game world size (background)? Any ideas? I dont need example (but if someone have a time please update my jsfiddle...)

Comment: What you need is the x ratio and y ratio (canvasWidth / bgWidth) then you multiply all your values (x, y, width, height) by this ratio on both images and you've got it. http://jsfiddle.net/01sLdpb8/8/ Not answering because there are so much to tell on your code... (check that your images are loaded, don't run an useless rAF loop like that etc.)

Answer (score 1):

1. `new Image;` should be `new Image();`
2. Here is the Update https://jsfiddle.net/01sLdpb8/39/, Change the size of `<canvas>` by using `transform: scale();`
   You can try count the percent of scale u want and update the value.